# AJAX without UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Say you have a Grid which is having paging, editing and extra, I usually put the whole grid in UpdatePanel to make the page partially render with AJAX, but I hear that u can do AJAX without UpdatePanel, how is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

[ScottGu's Blog : Tip/Trick: Cool UI Templating Technique to use with ASP.NET AJAX for non-UpdatePanel scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx)

[Using Ajax, Beyond UpdatePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/UsingAjaxBeyondUpdatePane.aspx)